# Inserting permissions to Google Drive file using PyDrive

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, pydrive

I am using PyDrive to create a Google Sheets file on a Google Shared Drive, the below code snippet successfully creates the file in my shared drive folder:

```
f = gd.CreateFile(
            {'title': name, 'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet', 'parents': [{'teamDriveId': '1234', 'id': '1234'}]})
        f.Upload(param={'supportsTeamDrives': True})
```

On adding the file, I am also trying to set permissions for an email address to gain write access to the file as below:

```
f.InsertPermission({'type': 'user', 'value': 'myemail@email.com', 'role': 'writer'})
```

On attempting to add the permissions, I receive the below error:

```
<HttpError 404 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/file_id_here/permissions?alt=json returned "File not found: file_id_here">
```

I have checked and the file id appears to be the same as the one that has been created.

I assumed that it wouldn't be any authorisation issue if I am able to create the file? Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata` scope?

Comment: I am using the default https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive scope which I think covers everything doesn't it?

Comment: It does, yes. Can you confirm that the ID is 100% correct by navigating to `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/file_id_here/edit#gid=0`?

Comment: Yes I can confirm that I am able to open the file fine from that link so the ID appears to be fine.

Answer (score 2):

I have found it appears to be an issue with no entry for 'supportsTeamDrives' in the PyDrive's files.py file in the InsertPermission function.

I added the 'supportsTeamDrives' parameter into the code at line 325 as follows and it now appears to work:

```
permission = self.auth.service.permissions().insert(
                fileId=file_id, body=new_permission, supportsTeamDrives=True).execute(http=self.http)
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way I found using pyDrive was doing this:

```py
file = gd.CreateFile({'title': 'filename', 'parents': [{'teamDriveId': '<your teamDriveId>', 'id': '<file id>'}]})
file.Upload(param={'supportsTeamDrives': True})
# here we can use the pydrive object to update.
new_permission = {
    'id': 'anyoneWithLink',
    'type': 'anyone',
    'value': 'anyoneWithLink',
    'withLink': True,
    'role': 'reader'
}
permission = file.auth.service.permissions().insert(
    fileId=file['id'], body=new_permission, supportsTeamDrives=True).execute(http=file.http)
```